Isolated Azure function throws InternalServerError while using "CreatedAtRouteResult" and the exception is not caught, but works with "CreatedResult"
I am trying to migrate my Azure function to Isolated function and followed the instructions as per Microsoft.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/migrate-dotnet-to-isolated-model?tabs=net8
After making the necessary code and package changes, when I test the function triggers, the trigger endpoints with "CreatedAtRouteResult" are failing with "500 InternalServerError" on postman and the exception is not caught in any of the TRY CATCH blocks.
Before the migration to Isolated functions, I was able to get the complete Route or the Url in the Location Header of the Response as shown in the below screenshot.

responseObject == null ? (IActionResult)new BadRequestResult()
: new CreatedAtRouteResult(
"GetEndpointName",
new { param1, param2 = param2value },
responseObject);

I am getting the below error on running(screenshot attached)

I tried changing it to "CreatedResult" and it works fine but that would force me to include the Location Header in the response manually which I don't want to.
I tried this:
responseObject == null ? (IActionResult)new BadRequestResult()
: new CreatedResult(
"GetEndpointRouteUrl",
responseObject);

This is my Program.cs file

Please guide me with this, thanks in advance!


it works fine but that would force me to include the Location Header in the response manually which I don't want to.

Yes, In isolated Functions AFAIK, CreatedAtRouteResult gives exception and in that you do not need a location header but when you use CreatedResult it requires Location Header to be given :

The code i used is similar as you have:
return new CreatedResult("testendpointurl", responseObject);

Output:

If you still not sure, then i would suggest you to raise a support request.
